# Finding a particular ODE solution using NDSolve on a vector field which passes through a given point

Tags: differential-equations

I have solved the vector field for the problem:

```
vfield1 [x_,y_] := { 1 - (x ^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)^2,-2x*y/(x^2+y ^2)^2}
pl1 = VectorPlot [ vfield1 [x,y] , { x, - 3, 3 } , { y, - 3, 3 } , VectorStyle -> Blue,
RegionFunction -> Function [{ x, y, vx, vy, norm } , ( x  ) ^ 2 + ( y ) ^ 2 >1 ]] ;
```

[image]

where vfield is a function of   $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$.

I want to find the path (the solution I suppose)  of a particle starting from point  (-4,1) and I need to determine an approximate value of how long T it takes for the particle to pass the rod and reach the vertical line x=4 on the opposite side of the cylinder.

Now the first  part , I thought I solve the original problem, and insert for x=-4 and y=1 in the original  vfield1. This gives the initial conditions to that problem, y(274/289)=8/289. So I would solve vfield1 with Ndsolve using IC y(274/289)=8/289.

However, I am not sure this is correct and how to write that code. Also, the second point on determining the value of how long time, I would have assumed I needed to differentiate the resulting solution with respect to t and insert for x=4 in that derivative. So assuming this is correct, I should have any complications doing the second part. But the NDSolve part is tricky.

I try

```
        eqn = { x ' [ t ] == vfield1 [ x [ t ] , y [ t ]][[ 1 ]] , y ' [ t ] == vfield1 [ x [ t ] , y [ t ]][[ 2 ]] } 
        sol11 = First @ NDSolve [ eqn ~ Join ~ { x [ 0 ] == 1, x ' [ 0 ] == 1 } , { x, x ' } , { t, 0, 30 }] 
Show [
    StreamPlot [ vfield1 [ x, y ] , { x, - 2, 8 } , { y, - 4, 4 }] ,
    ParametricPlot [{ x [ t ] , x ' [ t ]} / . sol11 // Evaluate , { t, 0, 30 } , PlotStyle -> Red]]>
```

But I get an error "Syntax
:"{x[t],x'[t]}/ cannot be followed by .sol11."

Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: `/ .` should be `/.` i.e. there should be no space between them.

Answer (score 6):

Try `NDSolveValue`:

```
odes = MapThread[#1 == #2 &, {{x'[t], y'[t]}, vfield1[x[t], y[t]]}]
XY = NDSolveValue[{odes, x[0] == -4, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]

Show[{pl1, ParametricPlot[Through[XY[t]], {t, 0, 10}]}]
```

[image]

Particle reaches `x==4`

```
NSolve[XY[[1]][t] == 4, t] (*{{t -> 7.94805}}*)
```

after 7.94 seconds!

Hopt it helps!

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, this looks great!I will look for the derivative, however,  what is the particular solution?

Comment: Particular solution is `XY`. Which derivative you're looking for?

Comment: I realized there is not need for looking for a derivative. You can ignore that message. Thanks

Comment: How did 7.94 appear? I tried your code of NSolve, but it didn't give any answer. In fact I get "Part specification XY〚1〛 is longer than depth of object"

Comment: What did you try you should provide more details than "I tried your code of NSolve, but it didn't give any answer". I checked my code on a fresh kernel, works fine!